# vector containing only the last n-elements

Tags: c++, vector

I try to get some kind of buffer only containing the last n-elements. So if a new Value arrives forget the last one in the buffer. What I did so far was:

```
vector<double> buf;
buf.assign(n,0);

while(1) {
  memcpy(&buf[1],&buf[0],sizeof(double)*(n-1));
  buf[0] = SomeNewDouble;
}
```

I don't know how performent this is though. Is there a better way to do this?

Limitations:

- It has to be a vector

OS: Linux using gcc/g++ (

Comment: With memcpy the source and destination should not overlap. Use memmove instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this a more cleaner and nicer implementation:

```
buf.pop_back();
buf.insert(buf.begin(), newVal);
```

If you are concerened about performance and you do more modifications than (random) access operations you could use a (linked) `std::list` instead:

```
std::list<double> list;
list.pop_back();
list.push_front(newVal);
```

Both `std::list::pop_back()` and `std::list::push_front()` are constant in time (`O(1)`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to use vector's. Does the pop_back not shrink the vector and then then insert again increase it's size?

Comment: @magu_ Yes it changes the `size` of the vector but not the `capacity` which means no reallocation is done, thus I wrote the `pop_back()` before the `insert()`. Notice though that `insert()` must relocate the elements (like you also do already with your memcpy call) which means that the complexity is `O(n)` for this call. It boils down to the same performance wise, but it is much cleaner to read.

Comment: Ah true, I forgot about the diff. between size and capacity. Thank you for your answer

Comment: As you deleted a post on another thread that I though was unfairly downvoted you get a +1 here

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) which already simulates the FIFO behavior you want.

```
const int n;                     // your n
std::queue<double> buffer;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)      // initialize with n zeros
    buffer.push(0);

while (true) {
    buffer.pop();                // forget last one
    buffer.push(SomeNewDouble);  // push new one
}
```

Comment: Well I still need random access within the vector so queue might not be the way. And it need's also to be done with vector unfortunatly